# Getting Error while adding new MVC 4 Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, project

I am new to MVC. I have installed NuGet extension when i had installed MVC 4. After that i had run cleaner because of that i think temp files have been deleted. Now when i am trying to add any new MVC 4 Project it shows me following **ERROR**:

[image: Error that i got when trying to add new MVC project]

I have uninstalled **nuget** but still facing the same problem, please help me how can come out of this.

Comment: For one, type the error, don't paste a screenshot. Then search the web for the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the nuget package manager is not always installed by default. I came across this problem a few times already.

What you want to do is this.

**First**: You need to unistall **npm(nuget package manager)**, you did this already, you can try this again, just to be sure :)
*Visual studio -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Npm -> unistall*

**Second**: after you unistall npm, you need to install it again to use it (ofc). There are several ways to install npm:

- 1) install it under *Visual studio -> tools -> extenstions and
  Updates> npm -> install*
- 2) GOTO http://nuget.org, search the    install nuget link and click
  on it, downlaod the .vsix file and    install in on your visual studio

**Third**: after the installation, close and re-open visual studio, hopefully you will never get that error again.